# How to check which command button is clicked in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton, commandlink

I have 1 command button and 1 command link which are calling same method "testGet" in action.
How we can check which button is clicked in apex method? With command link, I am passing param which is setting globally so even after command button click, those will be available so I cant check with that.

Please help.

Thanks,
Sonam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing parameter you can simply call different methods which will be much more simpler to handle.

```
public String calledFrom{get;set;}

public void calledFromButton(){
    calledFrom = 'button';
    mainMethod();
}

public void invokedFromLink(){
    calledFrom = 'link';
    mainMethod();
}

public void mainMethod(){
    // main logic
}
```